# Issue in importing Polymer dependencies with AngularDart

Tags: polymer, dart-polymer, angular-dart, dart-pub, polymer-2.x

Resolving dependencies...
Package polymer has no versions that match >=1.0.0 <2.0.0 derived from:
my-app depends on version ^1.0.0
Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `package:polymer` hasn't been updated in quite since time, so old dependency ranges are likely to blame here. There is a community supported new version of PolymerDart (https://www.dart-polymer.com/) that might work better - but my recommendation is not to mix Polymer and AngularDart in the same application at this time.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, for your recommendation, So how should I apply material design to my AngularDart project